# How are proof techniques formulated in mathematical logic?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

How are proof techniques formulated in mathematical logic, for example:

- direct proof,
- proof by contrapositive,
- proof by contradiction?

Are the following   some possible ways?

1. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#Relationship_with_other_proof_techniques)  formulates them **as some  logical equivalence
   identities**. How are the identities used in proofs as proof techniques?  Is it by "if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent, then $\Phi \models \phi$ iff $\Phi \models \psi$ for any set $\Phi$ of formulas" and "if $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are logically equivalent, then $\Phi \models \phi$ iff $\Psi \models \phi$ for any formula $\phi$"?
2. Does p35 of Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic   formulate proof by
   contraction **at some metalanguage level using "iff" to connect two
   instances of $\models$**?

   > 4.4 Lemma.  For all  $\Phi$  and all $\phi$, $\Phi \models \phi$  iff  not  Sat  $\Phi \cup \{ \neg \phi \}$.

   How are other proof techniques formulated **at some metalanguage
   level using "iff" to connect two instances of $\models$**?
3. Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic formulates proof by contradiction and proof by contrapositive, **as some inference rules in the sequent calculus**, e.g. IV.2.4  *Contradiction Rule (Ctr)* on p63 for proof by contradiction, and IV.3.3 *Contrapositon Rules  (Cp)* on p64 for proof by contrapositive. Notice that the inference rules are one-directional, while proof techniques are bi-directional by nature, which the other possible ways of formulations have shown. So how can inference rules be used for representing bi-directionalness of proof techniques?
4. What are other ways for formulating proof techniques, if any?

Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a negation sign missing in the quote.

Comment: Usual rules of inference of propositional and predicate logic formalize the "basic" proof technique. See [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4)

Comment: See e.g. the rule of Negation Introduction: "if $\Phi, \varphi \vdash \bot$, then $\Phi \vdash \lnot \varphi$". Lemma 4.4. above is the semantical counterpart of the rule.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What is the semantical counterpart for proof by contrapositive?

Comment: What does it mean? Please, be precise with references... In Ebbinghaus, page 64, there are four Contraposition rules: each one “implement” a valid argument. Example: if $\Gamma \varphi \vDash \psi$, then $\Gamma \lnot \psi \vDash \lnot \varphi$”

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what do $Γ$ and $⊨$ mean in $Γ⊨$? Does $Γ$  mean $Γ \cup \{\}$ not  $\models$ version of a sequent, $Γ \models $ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is a proposition, then $P$ is equivalent to $\neg P\Rightarrow false$.