# Deduction rules involving set $\Gamma$ of premises versus elementary textbook natural deduction rules. How do they differ exactly?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

In elementary textbooks, natural deduction rules are presented in the following way, say, for $\&$-Intro

from $\phi$ and $\psi$, infer $\phi\&\psi$

or

$(n).....\phi$

$(m)....\psi$

$\therefore$

$(p)....\phi\&\psi$.

I would like to know to what extent does the following way of stating $\&$-Intro differs from the above  " ordinary" textbook presentation. The way I'm referring to is the one I find in Shapiro's presentation of classical logic (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Dedu):

***(&I) If Γ1⊢θ and Γ2⊢ψ, then Γ1,Γ2⊢(θ&ψ).***

( meaning : " if $\theta$ is derivable from a set of premises $\Gamma_1$ anf if $\psi$ is derivable from a set of premises $\Gamma_2$, then $(\theta\&\psi)$ is derivable from a set of premises $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$.")

Can Shapiro's presentation be termed " ***natural deduction***"? Or rather is it a case of " ***sequent calculus"***?

Aside : Do you know any beginner's textbook on mathematical logic that displays examples of derivations in Shapiro's style?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3774575/288417) answer your question? See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3818869/288417).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems to me that my qustions wrongly assumes that sequent calculus and natural deduction are two different genera , while it seems that natural deduction iis the genus and sequent calculus is a species ( another one being natural deduction operating on formulas like in elementary textbooks). Is this right? ( The meaning of " operating on sequent " and " operating on formulas" is not absolutely clear to me).

Comment: [Chiswell & Hodges](https://books.google.it/books?id=c4QSDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: No real difference at all; rules are applied to build derivations. Thus, when you use them you have always a "context": the premises to which you directly apply them and the remaining part of the derivation: assumption, other branches, and so on.

Comment: See also the post [Do inference rules mean the same in a Hilbert system and in a natural deductive system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819814/do-inference-rules-mean-the-same-in-a-hilbert-system-and-in-a-natural-deductive) about different styles of presenting a proof system.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'elementary textbook' rule is that: *when $\phi$ and $\psi$ may be derived, then we may infer that $\phi\mathop\&\psi$ may be derived*.   It is unstated that these derivations take place in the same context ( premises and assumptions ).   This rule of inference might be sumarised as $$\dfrac{~\phi\qquad\psi~}{\phi\mathop\&\psi}{\small\&\mathsf I}$$

The 'sequent calculus' rules extend this to explicitly list under which context things are derived.   The same rule above may be then presented with the context ($\Gamma$, a set of statements) explicitly stated: $$\dfrac{~\Gamma\vdash\phi\qquad\Gamma\vdash\psi~}{\Gamma\vdash\phi\mathop\&\psi}{\small\&\mathsf I}$$

We can then extend the rule so to say: *when $\phi$ and $\psi$ may be derived* in contexts $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ respectively, *then we may infer that $\phi\&\psi$ may be derived* in the united context, $\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$.

$$\dfrac{~\Gamma_1\vdash\phi\qquad\Gamma_2\vdash\psi~}{\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2\vdash\phi\mathop\&\psi}{\small\&\mathsf I}$$

---

Long story short: the advanced presentation says the same thing as the elementary presentation, but with some additional details added.